# Where does MacOS Finder keep this information (the origin of a file that was sent to me)?

Tags: files, filesystems, osx, ls, stat

I want to get the name of the person who sends me a specific file.
I've tried different types of `file`, and `stat`, but none of them seems to solve my problem. By the way, I'm currently using MacOS. Here is an example of a file I've got using AirDrop.

[image]

The name I want is marked by the red circle.

Comment: What makes you think that the author of a file is encoded into the file? Most office suites do that, and possibly some media or image manipulation software, but generally what you ask for is not possible. That is, in general you have to keep track of the source of your files yourself.

Comment: So to be clear. I want the computer name that created the file. The information is probably stored somewhere since it's shown in the Finder app, though I'm not sure where that may be.

Comment: That data is stored in Spotlight data stores. Try `mdls filename`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `mdls` from the command line to list meta data. Is this what you are looking for? If so, it may have been useful to use `apropos metadata` from the command line to get a list of software related to the search term, metadata. Sorry, I can't translate the language in the picture to English to know for sure if the `mdls` command provides what you want.

```
mdls -- lists the metadata attributes for the specified file

SYNOPSIS
mdls [-name attributeName] [-raw [-nullMarker markerString]] file ...

DESCRIPTION
The mdls command prints the values of all the metadata attributes
associated with the files provided as an argument.

The following options are available:

-name        Print only the matching metadata attribute value. Can be
             used multiple times.

-raw         Print raw attribute data in the order that was
             requested.  Fields will be separated with a
             ASCII NUL character, suitable for piping to xargs(1) -0.

-nullMarker  Sets a marker string to be used when a requested
             attribute is null.  Only used in -raw mode.
             Default is "(null)".

SEE ALSO
mdfind(1), mdutil(1) xargs(1)

Mac OS X              June 3, 2004                         Mac OS X
```

Comment: mdls is exactly what i want. Thank you very much!

Comment: `mdls -name kMDItemOriginSenderDisplayName` was the specific thing